# How to detect when a hotkey (shortcut key) is pressed

Tags: .net, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

How do I detect when a shortcut key such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> is pressed in a WPF (independently of any particular control)?

I tried capturing `KeyDown` but the `KeyEventArgs` doesn't tell me whether or not <kbd>Control</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> is down.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        // CTRL is down.
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any other ways to register shortcut keys, e.g. in XAML?

Comment: Check this thread out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612966/keyboard-events-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to do this with Commands in XAML. Unfortunately if you want to use a custom command name (not one of the predefined commands like ApplicationCommands.Open) it is necessary to define it in the codebehind, something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public static class CustomCommands
    {
        public static RoutedCommand MyCommand = 
            new RoutedCommand("MyCommand", typeof(CustomCommands));
    }
}
```

The XAML goes something like this...

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.DemoWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    Title="..." Height="299" Width="454">
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Control+O" Command="local:CustomCommands.MyCommand"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommands.MyCommand" Executed="MyCommand_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
</Window>
```

And of course you need a handler:

```
private void MyCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the command. Optionally set e.Handled
}
```

Comment: You can also create a RoutedUICommand and associate a particular keyboard gesture to the command as well to avoid having to place the KeyBinding code in each window you may want to implement this in.