# Easiest way to execute a command if KeyDown-event is fired in WPF MVVM with VB.NET?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

i want to execute a command if the KeyDown-event occurs. This command should only be fired if the Enter-Key was pressed.

How can I realize that in a MVVM-architecture?

I am using WPF and VB.NET.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard events in a WPF MVVM application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612966/keyboard-events-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to implement some kind of AttachedBehavior which allows you to hook a ViewModel command to a KeyDown event.

Usually I use the code posted [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/attachedcommandbehavior-aka-acb/) for attaching VM Command's to XAML Events, however I have not tested it with a KeyDown event.

If that doesn't work, I believe other 3rd party toolkits such as Prism or MVVM Light have their own implementation of the behavior

Answer (score 3):

I don't mind letting my view handle clicks. It's there to handle user interaction right? It just has to tell the view model what to do. MVVM easy button!

```
Private Sub FinishButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnFinish.Click
    'Get your view model from your datacontext
    Dim objVM As MyViewModel = CType(Me.DataContext, MyViewModel)

   'Execute command in your view model
   objVM.FinishCommand()
End Sub
```