# Textbox Enter Key event not working in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

The keydown event is not working properly.  I want to raise the same event as the button when the enter key is pressed.  Here is the c#

```
    public partial class Search : Control
    {
        public SearchRevision()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SearchViewModel vm = this.DataContext as SearchViewModel;
            if (vm != null)
                vm.Refresh();
        }

        private void myTextBox_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                SearchViewModel vm = this.DataContext as SearchViewModel;
                if (vm != null)
                    vm.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void myTextBox_Escape(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                txtName.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the error message? Put a breakpoint in the `KeyDown` method and see if it's being hit. Also, you should move your ViewModel code to its own method as you're repeating the same thing twice. Call this method from the button click handler and the keydown handler.

Comment: For MVVM, this is the
[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7086853/873979)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There is no need to write the code two times. You could do like this too.

```
private void myTextBox_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //you may pass the parameters if you need
        Button_Click_1(null,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question as the answer is for Windows Forms and the question is WPF? The KeyEventArgs.KeyCode only exists on the System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs and not on the WPF System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs same class names but different namespaces and different properties and methods.

Comment: I agree with Rodney Foley, e.KeyCode is NO exist on WPF textbox.

Answer (score 7):

in wpf there is no keycode or keys.enter
instead you can use :

```
private void myTextBox_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        SearchViewModel vm = this.DataContext as SearchViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
            vm.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In WPF, TextBox element will not get opportunity to use "Enter" button for creating KeyUp Event until you will not set property: AcceptsReturn="True".

But, it would`t solve the problem with handling KeyUp Event in TextBox element. After pressing "ENTER" you will get a new text line in TextBox.

I had solved problem of using KeyUp Event of TextBox element by using Bubble event strategy. It's short and easy. You have to attach a KeyUp Event handler in some (any) parent element:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TextBox_EnterButtomEvent.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBox_EnterButtomEvent"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid KeyUp="Grid_KeyUp">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height ="0.3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
            Input text end press ENTER:
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
            You have entered:
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# logical part (KeyUp Event handler is attached to a grid element):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            TextBox txtBox = e.Source as TextBox;
            if(txtBox != null)
            {
                this.txtBlock.Text = txtBox.Text;
                this.txtBlock.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RESULT:

[Application main window with result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctT8t.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In WPF sometimes "Key.enter" is not recognized and you must use "System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter" instead

```
if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
{
    //Your code here
}
```

I had the same problem as OP and this is the solution that worked for me.