# Mvvm TextBox KeyDown Event

Tags: events, mvvm, keydown

I'd like to know how I can handle a KeyDown Event with MVVM in my ViewModel.

I have a TextBox and when the user hits a key, which is not a number, the input shouldn't be allowed. I'd normally do it with Code behind like this (not full code, just an easy example):

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{

    // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard.
    if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Now I want to put this somehow in my ViewModel with a Command. I'm new to MVVM and I'm only using Bindings right now (which works fine :) ), but I don't know how to use a Command at all...

My TextBox looks i.e. like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyField, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private string _myfield;
public string MyField{
  get { return _myfield; }
  set { 
    _myfield= value;
    RaisePropertyChanged( ()=>MyField)
  }
}
```

But the setter will only be called, when I leave the TextBox + I don't have access to the entered Key.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612966/keyboard-events-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application

Comment: Thanks. Another question: I.e. I click on my TextBox, will this also raise the GotFocus Event? I have a decimal textbox with a standard value of 0.00. When I click in the TextBox, the value should be "" (if value 0.00 is in the TextBox). I see that UpdateSourceTrigger will raise my setter every time I type something in and that I'll have to check/set the value depending on the input... Anyway, "KeyDown" is working, but what about GotFocus?
PS: The above question shows how to raise an Event when I click a Key, but I want to handle all KeyDown events and not a special Key. (With no Behind-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this by using the interaction triggers.  (this example uses the MVVM_Light framework for the command binding)

here is an example:

```
<textBox Text="{Binding MyField}">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
             <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCommandName}" CommandParameter="YouCommandParameter"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
<TextBox/>
```

Create a ICommand object in your view model with the name MyCommandName and add these to the top of your xaml:

```
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
 xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```

You don't have to use the mvvm-light command.  This is just what I use and I like it because it allows me to use the CanExecute method of the ICommand interface

hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

I know my answer is late but if someone has a similar problem. You must just set your textbox like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyField, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: This is great and simple. To expand this I found the following additional info about how it works: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507883/UpdateSourceTrigger-Property-in-WPF-Binding. Great stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The following works for handling the "Enter" key in a TextBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding UploadNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding 
          Key="Enter" 
          Command="{Binding FindUploadCommand}" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```