# How to receive KeyDown event within an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I got a pretty complex WPF-Window with a lot of sub controls using strict MVVM. One of them is an ItemsControl.  What I want to accomplish is to propagate a PropertyChanged-Event to Items within the ItemsControl when the Alt-Key is pressed anywhere - not just when the ItemsControl is focused. How can I do that?

An example: when I press the LeftAlt-Key *anywhere* within the Main Window I want to change the text of a button which is part of an item within an ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

see [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612966/keyboard-events-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application)
 answer with more than 100 upvotes 
or consider using a Behavior  with command

Edit :
Behavior on the upper control(MainView i guess) to register to the KeyDown Event and excute a command on your ViewModel

Comment: I don't think my question has something to do with that question. I don't want to know how I receive a KeyDown Event via MVVM. I want to "capture" the KeyDown-Event on every Item within the ItemsControl.

Comment: Ok,have you also ruled out Behaviors ?

Comment: When I use a Behavior on the MainView, how do I get it down to the ViewModels of the ItemsControl's Items? To do this I have to iterate through all Items in the Items-Control, get the Item's ViewModel (via Datacontext) and change the ViewModel's Property, right?

Comment: MainView->MainViewmodel via command and from there to other viewmodels,how do you communicate between viewmodels ?,EventAggregator or a service ?

Comment: if you have trouble passing the event/command maybe the Behavior can be on your Current View that is connected to the Current ViewModel , depends on how your view is organized