# How to detect keypress in TextBox using MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

In my ViewModel, how can I detect what key was pressed when entering text in a textBox?

In plain WPF/C# I'm doing it like this...

### XAML File

```
<TextBox x:Name="myInputField" KeyDown="inputField_KeyDown"/>
```

### Codebehind .xaml.cs

```
private void inputField_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

#### EDIT:

FYI -What I'm trying to do is create a shortcut for the enter key.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086853/6741868), it should help with your MVVM structure.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to go about this. The first approach would be more MVVM appropriate where we just detect a change to the value of the `Text` that is bound to your `TextBox`:

In XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myInputField", 
         Text="{Binding MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

In VM

```
private string myText;
public string MyText
{
   get
   {
       return myText;
   }

   set
   {
       if (Set(nameof (MyText), ref myText, value))
       {
            // the value of the text box changed.. do something here?
       }
   }
}
```

Or, to more directly answer the question you asked, if you must rely on detecting a keypress in the textbox, you should take advantage of the `EventToCommand` [that you can hook in with MVVMLight](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/)

In XAML:

```
xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

...

<TextBox ....
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.KeyDownCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>    
</TextBox>
```

**Edit**

In addition, you could also bind to the KeyBinding Command on the textbox:

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="False">
<TextBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding 
        Key="Enter" 
        Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}" />
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```

And yet another option would be to keep handling the KeyDown event in your view, but in the codebehind call a ViewModel method:

Comment: @ flyte Sorry but I'm stuck, I'm not sure how to capture the value of the key in my ViewModel. Would you mind elaborating a little more on how to receive the value in the ViewModel (in your second example)? FYI -What I'm trying to do is create a shortcut for the enter key and I don't think I can accomplish that with the first method.

Comment: You are able to pass the EventArgs to the Command in your VM. Please have a look at the `Getting the EventArgs to the ViewModel` section on the MVVMLight link I provided.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you actually do not want to send the `Key` to `ViewModel`. You just want to trigger something inside your `ViewModel`.

`EventAggregator` might be your solution, in your `KeyDown` event, you trigger event inside VM without knowing VM and you pass anything you want, there are several ways to do it.

If you are using framework like `MVVMLight`, `Prism` they might have own implementations, if you don't, there is a simple [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/812461/Event-Aggregator-Pattern) for it. (This is not the only way, you can find different implementations when you search `observer pattern`)

Inside your `if` you call `Publish` method which comes from `EventAggregator`. And all your Subscribers get that with a parameter you choose.

This way you can communicate with your `ViewModel` from wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have created a `Behavior` as follows:

```
public class KeyUpToCommandBehaviour : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(KeyUpToCommandBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Key", typeof(Key), typeof(KeyUpToCommandBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(default(Key)));
    private RoutedEventHandler _routedEventHandler;

    public Key Key
    {
        get { return (Key) GetValue(KeyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KeyProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        _routedEventHandler = AssociatedObject_KeyUp;

        AssociatedObject.AddHandler(UIElement.KeyUpEvent, _routedEventHandler, true);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_KeyUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var keyArgs = e as KeyEventArgs;

        if (keyArgs == null)
            return;

        if(keyArgs.Key == Key)
            Command?.Execute(null);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.RemoveHandler(UIElement.KeyUpEvent, _routedEventHandler);
    }
}
```

And then use it as

```
<TextBox ....
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <attachedBehaviors:KeyUpToCommandBehaviour Key="Enter" Command="{Binding OpenFxTradeTargetingWizardCommand}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```