# How to hook keyboard event in .NET Core using C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, .net-core

In .NET Framework I could easy hook global keyboard events, but using .NET Core it is different, since Unix doesn't provide kernel.dll as Windows. How to hook keyboard events using .Net Core?

Comment: What kind of .NET core project is this?

Comment: If you use WPF, have you tried InputBindings as proposed here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612966/keyboard-events-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application/7086853#7086853 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this in .NET Core. You'll need to write platform-specific code to do this on each platform you're deploying to.